# Convert 3 letter month column into a month number in Databricks SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a column with month - Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr etc.

I would like to query the data and order the resultset but having a month name makes in difficult.

How can I change the 3 letter month to a month number  so that I can use > or < operator and order by month number.

I am writing these queries on Azure Databricks SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **TO_DATE** function to convert a string to a date in Databricks SQL.  Then  use the **month()** function to convert the month into **month number**.

```sql
SELECT month(to_date(<column-name>, 'MMM')) AS month_number from <table-name>
```

The query will return the month number for the month in the column-name. The `to_date` function converts the `<column-name>` value to a date format using the format 'MMM', which specifies that the input string is a three-letter month abbreviation. The resulting date is then passed to the `month` function, which extracts the month number from the date.

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to convert the month name to month number:

```sql
SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(month_name, '%b')) AS month_number
FROM your_table
```